# How can I change the colour of PHP functions?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code to edit PHP files. This setting lets me change the colour of the functions that I define myself:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "functions": "#000000"
},
```

But it doesn't affect the colour of the functions that come with PHP and that are called in my code. They're still in some brown. That's too close to the grey I chose for my comments and I want to change it to plain black.

How can I change that colour?

Comment: `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes`

Comment: @Alex Google wasn't able to help me explain what you mean. Can you please make your comment useful?
To all: Thanks for downvoting. VS Code suggested asking questions here. Maybe they're to blame for recommending SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute from command palette `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes`. Find needed scope for function. Apply like this(no idea if this selector works for php):

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "support.function",
                "entity.name.function",
                "meta.function-call support.function",
                "meta.function-call entity.name.function",
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#40b18c",
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: By using the 'Inspect TM scope' command you can see that PHP uses `support.function` as scope for functions. I added `support.function` to the scopes covered by the 'tokenColorCustomizations .functions' setting.
So in the 1.12 release, this should work as you expected. Until then, use the way described in the comment.

Comment: Thank you. I just used the config snippet as shown and changed the colour. I can't make sense of the info shown with the command you mentioned. Too internal for me.

Comment: @ygoe you can find more info here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules